# Dynamic textbox with jquery how can I take the value dynamically from the servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add").click(function() {
    var intId = $("#masIng div").length + 2;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"ExtraIng\" id=\"div" + intId + "\"/>");
    var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"Ingr" + intId + "\"   placeholder= \"Añadir ingrediente...\"   />");
    fieldWrapper.append(fName);
    $("#masIng").append(fieldWrapper);
  });
});
```

This code creates several textboxes with the name = `Ing+<number of the current textbox>`.

Servlet:

```
public class AnyadirReceta extends HttpServlet {       
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {   
       String Ing1 =  request.getParameter("Ing1");
       String Ing2 =  request.getParameter("Ing2");
       .
       .
       .
```

I want to get all values of the Textboxes dynamically because I don't know how many there are.
Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerate over the parameter names of the request like following:

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  Enumeration<String> parameterNames = reqest.getParameterNames();

  while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {

    String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();
    String[] paramValues = req.getParameterValues(paramName);
    // do stuff with your values here

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sending these request parameters in an array, but if you want to keep the current code, you can use *request.getParameterNames()* or *request.getParameterMap()*:

```
public class AnyadirReceta extends HttpServlet {       
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {   
        for(String parameterName : request.getParameterNames()){
            String ing = request.getParameter(parameterName);
            //Process the parameter
        }
}
```

I give here a very basic example as a starting point if you want to use a more dynamic way of handling the parameters. Your front-end could generate something like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="ExtraIng" id="div1" <input type="text" name="ing"/></div>
    <div class="ExtraIng" id="div2" <input type="text" name="ing"/></div>
    <div class="ExtraIng" id="div3" <input type="text" name="ing"/></div>
    <div class="ExtraIng" id="div4" <input type="text" name="ing"/></div>
    <div class="ExtraIng" id="div5" <input type="text" name="ing"/></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Then on the server side you can write:

```
public class AnyadirReceta extends HttpServlet {       
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
         String[] parameters=request.getParameterValues('ing');
    }
}
```

Cheers,
A.

Comment: I fail to see the essential difference to my answer.